# Multiplayer mode doesn't find any servers

Tags: ps4, the-last-of-us

So I wanted to play The Last of Us multiplayer, but when I want to join a server it's not finding any server! My friend invited me to his private match, but when i pressed join nothing happened. I changed my DNS to Google DNS, and the same thing happens. I port forwarded my router and turned off the router firewall and the same thing happens. My internet connection has 250 kB/s download speed, and when I test my internet on PS4 it says all successful and NAT Type 2.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you connect to other games' online modes or even the PS Store?

Answer (score 2):

Try rebooting your router to see if they helps with the issue.

If you are able to setup "Port Forwarding", you should forward the following ports to the PS4 to help with the issue (check the user guide for your router for instructions on how to set this up):

- 1935
- 3478-3480

If you don't want to setup port forward, you can always put your PS4 in the DMZ (again check the manual to see how to set this up). This will open up all ports on the PS4, but also means your PS4 won't be protected by your router's firewall (and therefore allowing people to possible access it remotely). **This option should be used with caution and is the most risky solution.**